# mongodb: random obfuscation name java script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, javascript-objects

I am trying to obfuscate a string and so far I have been doing the search with the following command in the table:

'name': {'$regexFind': {'input': '$name', 'regex': /(\S+)$/}}

Lets say the name is John, to create a random string instead.

Is there a quick and simple way to do this in java script?